# Angular assigns value "two way", bug?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my html head I have an array. This is because I render it with a Django template and it's convenient.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> foo = ["Python", "Marketing", "Start-ups", "business"]
</script>
```

In my `directive.js` which has code for a directive I have:

```
$scope.foo = foo; // so it takes the data and the global value from the template
$scope.foo.push('wrong'); // let's add a value

$scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.foo = foo; // rebind with the global value
    console.log(foo)
}
```

When I log the `foo` I get `["Python", "Marketing", "Start-ups", "business", "wrong"]`.

Now I tried the same code omitting the `$scope.foo = foo;`. When I use the `reset()` the array is the correct array `["Python", "Marketing", "Start-ups", "business"]`.

What kind of sorcery is that?

Comment: Should $scope.passions be $scope.foo?  Also, what does the "two way" in your title mean?  I would recommend a plunker or a jsfiddle, as it's hard to tell what is a typo and what is correctly represented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand your question, but I'm going to take a stab.

If you do

```
$scope.foo = foo;
```

You are not making a copy of foo and assigning it to $scope.foo--$scope.foo now *references* the foo object.  So if you add items to foo, you will also be adding items to $scope.foo, and vice versa.

Note that this works for objects, not primitives (strings, ints, etc.).

This is the way javascript works--it has nothing to do with angularjs per se.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/M359DJzbywbSmg5OX6Zv?p=preview). If you press the button it does not reset the array. If I read correctly your answer you mean that it does not transfer the values but it replicates the object, right? So I have one object with two names? And if I change the `$scope.foo` it changes the `foo` as well.

Comment: It neither transfers the values nor does it replicate the object.  They are now both the same object.

Comment: If you don't want to change the original object create a copy using angular.copy. Instead of $scope.foo = foo use $scope.foo = angular.copy(foo)

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the explanation. I was about to write: "How can I later "reset" the foo? Store its values and if needed later reset its values." but @bekite answered to me. Do you possibly have a link I can read more about js's behavior on that? Thanks.

Comment: This video looks pretty good:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mh-hPzDfb_Q.  You might also search for "javascript reference types" or "javascript pointers" (although I don't think they are technically pointers).